# Do I need a Visa for a Schengen train trip with stop-over in other Schengen countries?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, germany, belgium

I am an Indian citizen with a US green card. I am going on a study abroad trip to London and I know I need a visa for that. However, I do plan to take a trip to Germany to visit my relatives via train (EuroStar and the ICE). I know the trains have stopovers in either Paris or Brussels but I am unsure of what the visa requirements will be for these countries, especially for France and Belgium since I would just be switching trains. I assume I would need a German visa as well.

What kind of permission do I need for traveling through these countries?

Comment: Get a Schengen visa as you are going to the Schengen area.

Answer (score 5):

Except some very specific documents (like those issued to people who applied for asylum so that they can wait for a decision), almost all visas or residence permit from Schengen area countries (which includes Belgium, France, and Germany) allow the holder to enter all other countries in the area.

Concretely, you will need to apply for a German short-stay Schengen visa and that visa will also automatically cover transit in France and Belgium.